# Configure SVN for Mac on LAN

Tags: svn

Can anyone help me in configuring svnserve on Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

I followed the instructions  mentioned below: 
http://www.tonyspencer.com/2007/03/02/setup-a-subversion-server-in-4-minutes/

I am able create and access repository from my mac.
I have configured svn with password but it will never prompt for password.

I would like to access the repository from my local network. Is there any settings missed in the tutorial..

thank you for any help...

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the following

```
 password-db = filename
 authz-db = filename
```

in the svnserve.conf file.

Comment: current settings are : 
 

anon-access = none

auth-access = write

password-db = passwd